# VBA copy file to .zip difficulty

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I am trying to package roughly 20-30 excel files into one zip to be emailed out after a process completes.  I am able to create the .zip file, and to copy files from one directory to another.  What I have not been able to do is copy a file into the .zip file.  Here is the code I have:

---

```
zipFile = "C:\testZip.zip"
zipPath = "C:\testZipFolder\"
NewZip (zipFile)
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
file = Dir(zipPath)
Set zipFolder = fs.getfolder(zipPath)
While (file <> "")
  If InStr(file, ".xlsx") > 0 Then
            I = I + 1
            Set f = fs.getfile("C:\" & file)
            f.Copy (zipPath)
            Debug.Print Err.Number
            Debug.Print Err.Description
```

NewZip is a method that creates the .zip file.  I can open the .zip and move a file to it manually.  When I run the above code I get error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.  If I change the destination path to some other folder, it will copy the file.